# html5 canvas question

Tags: html, canvas, reference

I have been experimenting with html5 quite a bit lately to see what I can build. In doing so I have looked at alot of examples especially from http://www.beautyoftheweb.com. In alot of the examples it seems like people that have created these applications can keep track of the elements on the canvas. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to keep a reference to an element on the canvas. Is it possible or are they doing something else to find the element. For example if I take an image and put it on the canvas I have no reference to that element except by doing canvas.getImageData(). If it is possible to keep a reference to an element it would be great if someone could give me an example of how to do so or a link to a tutorial would be great. If its not possible how are they doing it?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has to write their own code to remember whats drawn and how to interact with it. (Or else use a libarary).

I've actually written two tutorials on precisely this subject. They should be enough to get your started:

[Making and Moving Selectable Shapes on an HTML5 Canvas: A Simple Example](http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes)

[Selectable Shapes Part 2: Resizable, Movable Shapes on HTML5 Canvas](http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check this out when i have a free moment.

Comment: I'll be writing more tutorials in the future, so if there's something more complex you want a tutorial on drop me a line at my last name @acm.org and I'll see if I can include it.